# Trying to program a DSD TECH SH-A10 iBeacon with Sparkfun FTDI Basic

Tags: usb, serial, uart, wire, ftdi

I ordered some fairly random iBeacon (DSD TECH SH-A10), and I didn't realize that its configuration software is Windows only (http://www.dsdtech-global.com/2017/11/dsd-tech-bluetooth-config-tool.html), and I have a Mac. Nevertheless, I installed Wine and tried to run the software that way - but it doesn't recognize that my FTDI Basic is connected (there is no UART port option to subscribe to in the top left of the software). Next, I decided to go the more manual route of AT commands. I connected the iBeacon to my FTDI, and opened up CoolTerm (a serial terminal), and tried the standard "AT" test command. It didn't work, no response. I can see on the FTDI Basic that the transmit (TX) light flickers when I send the command, but nothing is received (RX).

I should mention that the whole time I am trying, I can see that the beacon is operating (or at least appears to be) because there is a red light that goes steady on and steady off. I think it is transmitting, but I think it has a default power of 0db (I was unable to detect the beacon using the default UUID and if the power is at 0db this would be why).

I can see the power level (and all the other parameters) in the configuration software when I run it with Wine, I'm just not sure if it is filler data/parameters or if it actually represents the data that pertains to my device...as I never connected the device to the software. I'm assuming each device comes with the same default data/parameters/settings, so there is no reason to believe that what I am seeing in the configuration software for settings is not correct.

Here are some pictures of the wire/FTDI/iBeacon setup:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about *usage* of an *undocumented* device, not about design engineering of something original from documented components.  Try the manufacturer support, or do a web search on the device and see if someone else has figured it out.

Comment: Note additionally that connecting logic level UART signals to a USB connector is entirely outside of ordinary standards; if that is actually what you are supposed to do and not a mistake, it must be leveraging some unique alternate capability of the device firmware (most USB capable MCUs do permit using the USB pins for alternate purposes, but *how exactly* the vendor of this "black box" might be leveraging that is knowable only to them until they chose to share details)

Comment: Ok thanks, I did email them asking for instructions for how to do it one way or another...AT or config software, there is little to nothing online, and the manufacturers website is not very helpful

Comment: As for the USB connector situation, it has to be run through a UART somehow...I have tried on my raspberry pi with `minicom` to connect but it says invalid I/0...with that way I had it plugged into a USB hub connected to the raspberry pi...maybe I should try removing the bulky casing and connecting it directly to the pi? Could the usb hub have been messing things up?

Comment: What is your basis for thinking that you should be connecting an FTDI device to the USB plug??  How did you decide which signal to connect to which pin? Most USB devices that operate in a serial mode do so by *proxying* the serial traffic through the USB protocol, and appear as a *virtual* serial device to the host.

Comment: to connect the iBeacon to the UART, so you are saying there is a proxy controlling the release of the serial traffic...and it may not be allowing the release?

Comment: And have you even checked that this "not supposed to exist" USB changer has continuity from one end to the other and isn't swapping the wires internally in some odd way?

Comment: yes i have checked for continuity, i made the wire (obviously i think :)), I have not checked for continuity for the data wires...my multimeter tongs don't fit into the usb connector area to touch the metal, it is a standard USB wire, red/white/green/black

Comment: So basically you just randomly twisted together some wires of traditionally incompatible purpose, and hoped for the best?

Comment: Well I was working under the assumption that the data transfer works in the same way that it would for say a UART to an ESP-8266 (or some other module) even if I make my own cord, and I guess I should find a way to test the data wires in the usb wire

Comment: That is not how USB works **at all**.  Not one bit.

Comment: how would u propose connecting the ibeacon to a UART? go back to raspberry pi and try it connected directly to pi?

Comment: Connect it with your e-waste disposal provider and purchase something with *documentation*.

Comment: lol, i did just buy another ibeacon...ill have it on sunday, sunday, sunday

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you needed to do was to:

1. plug the dongle directly into a USB port
2. install the [SiLabs driver](https://www.silabs.com/documents/public/software/Mac_OSX_VCP_Driver.zip) for your Mac
3. use the terminal app of your choosing to send the AT commands

No need for the crappy software

Comment: amazing...i thought i tried this...but i never looked to see that when you plug the USB in a new port shows up `SLAB_USBtoUART`